# Atualização real time em aplicativos Android

Tags: android, api, instagram-api

Olhando a `API` do instagram e fazendo pesquisas na internet me surgiu uma grande dúvida, como eles fazem a sincronização dos dados em Real Time sem precisar salvar “fotos e vídeos” no sqlite?

A documentação do [Instagram](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) fala que nossa aplicação pode ser notificada a cada atualização de fotos.

Porém é possível desenvolver algo parecido sem utilizar da `API` deles?

Eu poderia utilizar um `Observer` que a cada modificação dispara uma sincronização com meu servidor?

Minha intenção é criar algo parecido onde eu tenha uma atualização em real time.

Comment: Ora aqui está uma excelente pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja procurando o modelo de `push notifications` para receber na sua app notificações sobre o que acontece em tempo real em sua aplicação ou serviço web e em seguida baixar mais informações conforme necessário.

No Android é possível utilizar um dos muitos serviços disponíveis:

- [Google Cloud Message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)
- [Parse](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications)
- [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-android-get-started-push/)
- [Pushover](https://pushover.net/)
- entre outros.

Outra alternativa é criar sua própria arquitetura de push notifications, uma das partes mais complicadas é otimizar o sistema de pooling de informações do servidor para que não esgote os recursos do celular (bateria, memória, dados etc), e uma vez recebida a notificação de atualização fazer a sincronização dos detalhes em background com um Service.

Comment: Esse `push notifications` funciona como um observer? notifica um ouvinte? e realiza a "transação" ?

Comment: Sim, e você decide o que fazer com a notificação, por exemplo, alertar o usuário, enviar uma notificação, executar um método...

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino já tinha ouvido falar no Google Cloud Message, acho até que é o mais usado.

Comment: O google cloud message atende perfeitamente minha demanda

Answer (score 1):

Você pode trabalhar com o conceito de Services, que executa requisições ao servidor para checar de tempos em tempos se há algo novo e atualizar sua aplicação ou enviar uma notificação ao usuário.

Ou trabalhar com APIs como o Google Cloud Message, entre outras que possam facilitar suas requisições e notificações através de Push.

**Vantagens / Desvantagens:**

***Services -*** Você terá que defini-lo manualmente, o momento a ser iniciado, tempo, etc.

***Push Notifications -*** Você não precisa se preocupar o momento quando iniciar e quando encerrar, pois ele sempre estara "dormindo", só irá "acordar" quando houver algo novo no servidor.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Esse `push notifications `, trabalha como um notificador apenas?

Comment: Não, ele também pode executar algum método a sua escolha em Background.

Comment: Complementando minha resposta, se você optar por trabalhar com Services deverá ter em mente que ele pode consumir mais bateria dependendo da sua utilização, por exemplo se quiser que ele sempre notifique quando houver algo novo, deverá "inicia-lo" e deixa-lo aberto mesmo quando a aplicação estiver fechada, logo esse service ficara sempre rodando sem que o usuário possa ver.

Comment: muito bom, vou dar uma olhada nisso hoje a noite.